# how to block access for RSS Feed using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ddos

My website is experiencing RSS Feed problem

I get this htaccess code

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

but it blocks all IP address i just need to block mywebsite.com/feed.php from all IP address

Kind Regards

Comment: You can remove the file or put "exit;" on the second line.

Answer (score 2):

Using a .[htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file is equivalent to putting a <[Directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)> block in your server or vhost configuration. Without any further restriction the directives will apply to all of the files in the directory tree rooted at the filesystem location where the .htaccess file exists. When you want to act upon scpecific files, this is he wrong tool for the job you are trying to do.

The <[Files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files)> directive is the one you should be using to solve this problem, preferably in your main server or vhost configuration rather than a .htaccess.

Comment: Iain would you please guide me what to do